# buffered store used in a package throws an error

Tags: package, store, buffered

In EXTJS 6.7 I'm trying to use a buffered store in a grid inside a package and getting this

error:ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=1690868967014:118253 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')

what could be the problem?

when I'm using a regular data store it works fine, also when the same code is used not inside a package it works fine as well